# Host laravel application inside laravel application

Tags: php, laravel, apache, nginx

I am trying to host a laravel inside a laravel application because I need it to work on the same domain.

So imagine my domain is somedomain.com. I am already pointing it to the public directory of a laravel project. Now I need to host another laravel project at the same domain (not subdomain).

How can I do this? For example `somedomain.com/foo/bar` to point to the public directory of another laravel project using nginx or apache?

EDIT

I tried the solution from `flakerimi`, and it half works for now. I am not sure what I am doing wrong.

So I went to the apache conf for the laravel application sitting on mydomain.com and made the `Alias /email /dir/to/other/laravel/public` change and sure now all the `/email` routes are going to the other laravel application. I know this because it redirecting to `email/login`.

But I see a 404 on all `/email/` routes, but not a laravel 404, a apache 404 page. Which means that apache is going to the other laravel application but it is not able to use the routes there correctly.

I tried placing `RewriteBase /email` in the .htaccess file of the other laravel application but no luck. Any ideas anyone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just like you do in localhost

laravel1/public

laravel2/public

edit htaccess on laravel2
`RewriteBase /laravel2`

on apache

ServerName some.domain

```
## Path to laravel domain
DocumentRoot "/path/to/some/domain/laravel1/public"
<Directory "/path/to/some/domain/laravel1/public">
    AllowOverride All
</Directory>

## Path to laravel sub-folder
Alias /laravel2/ "/sites/laravel2/public"
<Directory "/sites/laravel2/public">
    AllowOverride All
</Directory>
```

also check `config/session.php` for both installations

L1

```
'cookie' => 'a_unique_name'
'path' => '/',
```

L2

```
'cookie' => 'a_unique_name_L2'
'path' => '/laravel2',
```

Comment: The `conf` file part seems to be working, the `/laravel2` routes are going to the other directory, but apache is complaining not found. I have a feeling I need to make some changes to `RewriteBase /laravel2`, maybe RewriteRule?

Comment: In nginx, it is working like `rewrite /mail/(.*)$ /mail/index.php?/$1 last;`

Comment: Yeah, my code is abstract, now you have to replace them with your config.

Comment: Oh no it worked, I forgot to add allow override in ssl section. Thanks man!